# MSWebDriver fails to run in Karate

Tags: karate

I am using Mac and installed Microsoft Edge but getting this error when I try to run the script. It works fine for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

```
* configure driver = { type: mswebdriver, showDriverLog: true}


23:26:42.311 request:
1 > POST http://localhost:17556/session
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 55
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: localhost:17556
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_242)
{"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"edge"}}}

23:26:42.321 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:17556 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), http call failed after 10 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:17556/session
23:26:42.322 http request failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:17556 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
23:26:42.323 driver config / start failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:17556 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), options: {type=mswebdriver, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
shopifysg.feature:10 - driver config / start failed: 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:17556 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), options: {type=mswebdriver, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't there on 0.9.5 but it is in the `develop` branch. You should use `msedgedriver`, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#driver-types

I think it is there in 0.9.6.RC1 - so can you try that first. If not, please help us by following the developer guide, so that we can release this sooner: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's not working in 0.9.6.RC1. I will try the develop branch.

Comment: @Vijay make sure you make the change as described in the `webDriverSession`, and if you are still seeing issues, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test | https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter. It worked well with 0.9.6.RC1 version itself. I had 2 issues. First issue was the MSEdgeDriver I was using was version 83.xx but the MSEdge version was 80.xx and this was throwing error. And then I had to manually start the MSEdgeDriver. Once I did this the script ran perfectly well on MSEdge browser.

Comment: @Vijay: Please post the code the launch the msedge browser

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you please help me in launching edge browser
  * configure driver = { type: 'msedgedriver', webDriverSession: { capabilities: { browserName: 'edge' } } }

This is not working, please share me right one

Comment: I honestly don't know, I use chrome. this requires research which some teams have done

Answer (score 1):

Update the Karate-core version greater than 1.1.0 it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).